# Rails gmaps4rails Map doesn't autoadjust

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

I followed the gmaps4rails v2 tutorial from youtube.

This is what happens...

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Explanation:** Randomly when I access to the view, it shows the maps partially and if I move the maps with the mouse (as the first two pictures) it never fills all the field...
Sometimes after n tries (just pressing F5...) it displays correctly (third picture) but later with another page reloading, it's like the first pictures.
I need to know what is happening.

**View:**

```
<div style='width: 600px;'>
    <div id="map" style='width: 600px; height: 300px;'></div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    //handler.fitMapToBounds();
    handler.getMap().setZoom(15);
    handler.map.centerOn(marker);
    });
  </script>
```

**controller:**

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@users) do |user, marker|
    marker.lat user.latitude
    marker.lng user.longitude
end
```

**model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    geocoded_by :current_sign_in_ip
    after_validation :geocode
end
```

I've tried with setZoom and fitMapToBounds but nothing changes...
I followed all the tutorial and github's guide.

**UPDATE:**

How could I show the users at the map in other model different to the user model?

Comment: this is a css issue, map's div must have clearly defined dimensions

Comment: there must be issues in your page, the example cannot be reproduced in isolation

Comment: My CSS file hasn't any div parameter on it. I'll try with another view.

Comment: How could I show the users at the map in other model different to the user model?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Comment: I have an app where the users create dreams. (Dreams are microposts).
I want to display the "dreams geolocation" (obviously, the users geolocation) but in that view (dreams view). Latitude and Longitude are in the users migration. Dreams should catch that variables from users model and with geocode, show with markers the dreams location.
Sorry if I am not clear enough...